# IntelliJ IDea: local artifacts unloaded from modules when import changes

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jar, sbt

I'm having a little problem with IntelliJ IDEA regarding the reference to certain local jars. The IDE allows me to referencing local project jar artifacts, and associating them to the project modules.

Now, every time I update the dependencies list in the **build.sbt** file:

[image]

each module lose the dependency to the local jar artifact:

[image]

so, each time I have to update the list of dependencies, I have to reference again each jar artifact to each module. Is there a way to avoid this behavior, in a way that the IDE would understand that it has to keep the reference to the local jar?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [SBT unmanaged dependencies](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Unmanaged+dependencies):

> Unmanaged dependencies work like this: add jars to `lib` and they will
>   be placed on the project classpath. Not much else to it!